# Update the list automatically after selecting the option with JavaScript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I want to update the list after choosing the option of another list

HTML code

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<form action="check-add.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center" height="60">students</span></td>
<td align="center" height="60"><select id="first-choice">
<option disabled selected>select students</option>
<option value="1">Mark</option>
<option value="2">Makarious</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" height="60">subject</td>
<td align="center" height="60">
 <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info" multiple data-max-options="7" data-live-search="true" id="second-choice"></select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" height="100" colspan="2">
<input type="submit" class="but" name="save-students" value="add"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
$("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());
}).trigger("change");
</script>
```

getter.php file

```
<?php
    @include("../include/config.php");

    $choice = @mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['choice']);
    $result = @mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE phases='".$choice."'");
    while($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</option>';
    }
?>
```

After choosing variable in this list
Does not update the second list
It does not appear the options
In the #second-choice

**I want JavaScript code to update automatically for the second list, but after choosing the option from the first menu**

Answer (score 0):

In getter.php, $choice would equal one of "select students", "1", or "2" from the first-choice values. Is that what you would expect?

I'm guessing from your SELECT statement that you would rather receive "", "Mark", or "Makarious". If that is the case, then first-choice should look like

```
<select id="first-choice">
  <option disabled selected value="">select students</option>
  <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
  <option value="Makarious">Makarious</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The problem is not the first option (first-choice)
The problem in the second option does not update the list of the second option (second-choice)
Supposed After choosing the first option sends variables to the second option
Using getter.php file

Comment: Have you verified what values are returning from getter.php? I suspect that the Javascript is working, but you are getting an empty option string from getter.php